# iPhone Creating custom images causes memory leaking

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I have a code that generates new image every time user moves slider a little and adds it to sublayer. It works except it leaks memory. What I am retaining that i shouldn't? However i think i am releasing everything as i should:

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value);

//add moon mask
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(400, 400), NO, 1);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 0, 0.8);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 0, 0.8);
int tempx = progressAsInt;
int x = tempx; 
if (x < 0) {
    isHigherThanHalf = YES;
    x = -tempx;
}
else {
    isHigherThanHalf = NO;
}

CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
BOOL onlyDrawTopHalf = isHigherThanHalf;
CGFloat halfMultiplier = onlyDrawTopHalf ? -1.0 : 1.0;
CGRect ellipse = CGRectMake(200-x/2, 0, 0+x, 400);

CGRect clipRect = CGRectOffset(ellipse, halfMultiplier * ellipse.size.width / 2, 0);
CGContextClipToRect(contextRef, clipRect);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, ellipse);
CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);

CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
onlyDrawTopHalf = !onlyDrawTopHalf;
halfMultiplier = onlyDrawTopHalf ? -1.0 : 1.0;
ellipse = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);

clipRect = CGRectOffset(ellipse, halfMultiplier * ellipse.size.width / 2, 0);
CGContextClipToRect(contextRef, clipRect);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, ellipse);
CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *data = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
//must free pixels
free(pixels);
pixels = (Byte *)[data bytes];


CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

// create a new image from the modified pixel data
size_t width                    = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t height                   = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerComponent         = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
size_t bytesPerRow              = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo         = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRef provider      = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, [data length], NULL);

CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreate (
                                        width,
                                        height,
                                        bitsPerComponent,
                                        bitsPerPixel,
                                        bytesPerRow,
                                        colorspace,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                        );
// the modified image
UIImage *newImage   = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
sublayer2.contents = (id)[newImage CGImage];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer2];
// cleanup
[data release];
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
```

I have added [data release] but there still seems to be some leaking.

EDIT - I have found that in addition to [data release] i need to close my image context by calling 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
The leaks have stopped.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the analyser say anything? Go to Product -> Analyze.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
```

data object is not released. you are using autorelease image object sometime it can results in memoryWarning.

```
UIImage *newImage   = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
```

It is always better to create object manually and then release when you are done with the object. because we never know when the autorelase pool will be drain.

Comment: Indeed the NSData object seems to leak, however, I'm not sure I agree the next statement: "we never know when the autorelease pool will be drain". In fact, we do know, it gets drained at the end of each run loop cycle. Which makes it perfectly safe to use in the same scope.

Comment: @valentina - I agree with you autorelease pool gets drain at the end of each run loop. but how will be assure that run loop end immediately and it is not taking time . Just curious to know more about run loop and all Please.

Comment: Why would you care when the run loop cycle ends as long as it won't end for sure while you are running the code in your current scope? You can't know for sure exactly when it ends, but you don't care either, it will end when all the code waiting to be executed is executed. The point is, as long as you use the autoreleased instance in the same scope, you will have absolutely no problems.